# Section of code gives an error when put in the paint event, but works in the timer tick event with a bad framerate

Tags: vb.net, graphics, timer, simulation

```
Public Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    For Each planet In planetsList
        Dim planetFill As Brush = New SolidBrush(planet.colour)
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(planetFill, planet.displayX - 5, planet.displayY - 5, 10, 10)
        Dim trailcolour As Pen = New Pen(planet.colour)
        For count As Integer = 0 To trailDots
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(trailcolour, planet.trailX(count), planet.trailY(count), 1, 1)
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If numberOfPlanets > 0 Or numberOfSuns > 0 Then
        For Each planet In planetsList
            For Each sun In sunsList
                ...
                trailDots += 1
                ReDim Preserve planet.trailX(trailDots)
                ReDim Preserve planet.trailY(trailDots)
                planet.trailX(trailDots) = planet.displayX
                planet.trailY(trailDots) = planet.displayY
            Next
         Next
         Me.Refresh()
    End If
End Sub
```

The purpose of this part of the code is to draw a trail behind a planet while it moves (My project is a gravity physics simulation). This works fine for one planet, but once a second planet is added it throws an error at the DrawEllipse line, saying 'IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled.'

I moved a few lines from the paint event to the timer tick event, so that it reads roughly like this:

```
trailDots += 1
ReDim Preserve planet.trailX(trailDots)
ReDim Preserve planet.trailY(trailDots)
planet.trailX(trailDots) = planet.displayX
planet.trailY(trailDots) = planet.displayY
Dim mygraphics As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics
Dim trailColour As Pen = New Pen(planet.colour)
For count As Integer = 0 To trailDots
    mygraphics.DrawEllipse(trailColour, planet.trailX(count), planet.trailY(count), 1, 1)
Next
```

This no longer gives an error message and the code works as expected aside from performance. Instead of drawing the trail as the planet moves, the trail is completely redrawn each time, from the starting location to the current location. So as time goes on the performance gets worse and worse, so each time the trail is drawn it takes longer than before. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: `trailDots` is apparently out of synch/not what you think it is.  A better way to loop would be `For count As Integer = 0 To planet.trailX.Count-1`.  Even then, it assumes that trailY will be the same size

Comment: @Plutonix Awesome, that works perfectly! Thanks a bunch. If you want you can repost that as an answer so I can mark it as solved

Comment: Go ahead an post a self answer if you want

Answer (score 0):

It was a quick fix.  The problem was that the `trailX` array size was not matching the `trailDots` indexer I was using.  Changing the loop to work off the actual array size fixed it:

```
For count As Integer = 0 To trailDots
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(trailcolour, planet.trailX(count), planet.trailY(count), 1, 1)
Next
```

Comment: I expanded the answer so it could be useful to other users.  As it was, it was kind of skimpy and got you a DV.

Comment: And dont forget you can tick your own answers as well- This helps other users see that the answer works.